# Multiple subreports in a RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I need to create multiple subreports in a single RDLC report

For example, in my scenario, i m going to make a report of projects. projects are grouped by departments and every project has multiple resources working on it. now i want to show sub report of resources beneath every row of project. so i need to add multiple subreports which will be equal to the number of projects available in database

i am new to RDLC, can any one please give me a link for detailed tutorial which can cover my scenario, Thanx in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got complete tutorial that helped me through reports an subreports. its on

http://shahfaisalmuhammed.blogspot.com/2011/10/building-subreport-in-reporting.html